# How to not insert an already existing record into a hash

Tags: perl

I am extracting data from a logfile and want to insert the data into a hash. The problem I have is that the hash has duplicate values and I can't figure out how to neglect already existing ones. My code looks like this:

```
  while(my $line=<F>) {
            # logfile pattern 31.05.2018 03:25:50 --- Start Deaktiviere PKonten ---
            $line =~ /^\s*([\d.]+) ([\d:]+) --- (.*) -.*\s*$/;
            $timestamp=join(" ",$1,$2);
            $action=$3;
            push @{$results{$action}} ,$timestamp;
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
'Start Ermittlung der Freibeträge Gesamt.' => [
                                                      '31.05.2018 03:28:45',
                                                      '31.05.2018 03:28:45',
                                                      '31.05.2018 03:28:45',
                                                      '31.05.2018 03:28:45',
                                                      '01.06.2018 03:54:49',
                                                      '01.06.2018 03:54:49',
                                                      '01.06.2018 03:54:49',
                                                      '01.06.2018 03:54:49',
                                                      '02.06.2018 03:30:11',
                                                      '02.06.2018 03:30:11',
                                                      '02.06.2018 03:30:11',
                                                      '02.06.2018 03:30:11',
                                                      '07.06.2018 03:14:45',
                                                      '07.06.2018 03:14:45',
                                                      '07.06.2018 03:14:45',
                                                      '07.06.2018 03:14:45',
                                                      '08.06.2018 03:33:36',
                                                      '08.06.2018 03:33:36',
                                                      '08.06.2018 03:33:36',
                                                      '08.06.2018 03:33:36'
                                                    ],
```

How can I get those duplicates out of the hash? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are not duplicate entries in your hash. It's duplicates in the array reference. That's a completely different problem, and probably why you get confused. Hashes in Perl cannot have duplicate entries.

Comment: Do you care about the order of the timestamps? If not, turn that inner array into a hash.

Comment: no the order is not so important at the moment. I am just looking for solution quickly

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the order of the timestamps, use a hash reference instead of  an array.

```
while(my $line = <$fh> ) {
    $line =~ /^\s*([\d.]+) ([\d:]+) --- (.*) -.*\s*$/;
    my $timestamp = join(" ", $1, $2);
    my $action = $3;

    # use a counting hash instead of a list
    $results{$action}->{$timestamp}++;
}
```

Your structure is now a bit different.

```
'Start Ermittlung der Freibeträge Gesamt.' => {
    '01.06.2018 03:54:49' => 4,
    '07.06.2018 03:14:45' => 4,
    '31.05.2018 03:28:45' => 4,
    '08.06.2018 03:33:36' => 4,
    '02.06.2018 03:30:11' => 4,
},
```

To access the timestamps, you need to use [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html).

```
say for sort keys %{ $results{$action} };
```

Of course that comes out sorted in a wrong way because the German date is `DD.MM.YYYY` and not `YYYY-MM-DD`. But you should have the [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) because the hash order is by design not reliable, so every program run would give you randomly arranged output.

Comment: The `.*\s*$`  in the regex is pointless. There's also a space between the date and time in the original string, so there's no need to take it out and put it back.

Comment: Order preserving: `push @{$results{$action}} ,$timestamp if !$seen{$action}{$timestamp}++;`

Comment: @Borodin that's true. But I haven't actually changed the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since the timestamps are ordered,

```
while(my $line = <$fh> ) {
    my ($ts, $action) = $line =~ /^\s*([\d.]+ [\d:]+) --- (.*) -/;

    my $actions = $results{$action} //= [];
    push @$actions, $ts
        if !@$actions
        || $actions->[-1] ne $ts;
}
```

---

In case I'm mistaken about the timestamps being ordered, here's an alternative.

Hashes aren't just useful for grouping; they are also useful for removing duplicates. The following is an idiomatic way of removing duplicates (while preserving order):

```
my %seen;
@a = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @a;
```

You could apply this to your solution as follows:

```
my %seen;
my %results;
while(my $line = <$fh> ) {
    my ($ts, $action) = $line =~ /^\s*([\d.]+ [\d:]+) --- (.*) -/;

    push @{ $results{$action} }, $ts
       if !$seen{$action}{$ts}++;
}
```

Comment: Fixed . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(my $line=<F>) {
        # logfile pattern 31.05.2018 03:25:50 --- Start Deaktiviere PKonten ---
        $line =~ /^\s*([\d.]+) ([\d:]+) --- (.*) -.*\s*$/;
        $timestamp=join(" ",$1,$2);
        $action=$3;

        my $value_in_array = grep {$_ eq $timestamp} @{$results{$action}};

        push(@{$results{$action}} ,$timestamp) 
           unless($value_in_array) ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove the duplicates from the array ref, you can do it this way. It will remove duplicates after the hash already built.

```
while(my $line=<F>) {
    # logfile pattern 31.05.2018 03:25:50 --- Start Deaktiviere PKonten ---
    $line =~ /^\s*([\d.]+) ([\d:]+) --- (.*) -.*\s*$/;
    $timestamp=join(" ",$1,$2);
    $action=$3;
    push @{$results{$action}} ,$timestamp;
}
foreach my $key (keys %result) {
    $result{$key} = [keys %{ {map {$_ => 1} @{$result{$key}}} }];
}
```

This solution should filter data as hash is built:

```
my %filter;
while(my $line=<F>) {
    # logfile pattern 31.05.2018 03:25:50 --- Start Deaktiviere PKonten ---
    $line =~ /^\s*([\d.]+) ([\d:]+) --- (.*) -.*\s*$/;
    $timestamp=join(" ",$1,$2);
    $action=$3;
    if(!defined $filter{$action}{$timestamp}) {
        push @{$results{$action}} ,$timestamp;
        $filter{$action}{$timestamp} = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want unique values for each array ref in the hash?

Comment: that doesn't work btw I get this error Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not map iterator) at ./tw_runtimes.pl line 29, near "}]"

Comment: still the same error: Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not single ref constructor) at ./tw_runtimes.pl line 29, near "}]"